# animated svg mask doesn't work in firefox

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, mask

h1 everyone, i'm trying to make a cross-browser animation based on svg mask for svg elements. At first, I caught a bug with css, in firefox mask doesn't work with css 'width' and 'height', only with inline properties. So, next question - how to animate mask for firefox, nothing harder that 'width resize'. https://codepen.io/flyby/pen/KmYOgb

```
<div id='cont'>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id='rectMask' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse' transform='scale(1)'>
        <rect x='0' y='0' id='maskRect' width='700' height='850'/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path id='maskedPath' d='m 0,0 l 650,0 -100,850 -550,0 z' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='riverPath' d='m 653,0 l -100,850' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='notMaskedPath' d='m 655,0 l 650,0 0,850 -750,0 z'/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#cont {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
}
svg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#maskedPath {
  stroke:none;
  fill:rgb(230,230,230);
}
#notMaskedPath {
  stroke:none;
  fill:rgb(230,230,230);
}
#riverPath {
  stroke:rgb(50,160,240);
  stroke-width:8;
  fill:none;
}
#maskRect {
  width:0px;
  height:850px;
  fill:white;
  stroke:none;
  animation: resize 3s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes resize {
  50% {width: 700px !important;}
  0%,100% {width: 0px !important;}
}
```

Comment: guys, wtf, wehre is all web gurus, and how to make a snippet from my code?

Comment: There is a little icon above the edit box that creates a snippet. The editor is very similar to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you have discovered, your can't (yet) set geometric properties, like `width` and `height` of SVG elements in Firefox.  It's not a bug. It's just an SVG 2 thing that Firefox has not implemented yet, but Chrome has.

The solution is to use the built-in SVG ("SMIL") animation elements, instead of CSS animation.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#cont {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
}
svg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#maskedPath {
  stroke:none;
  fill:rgb(230,230,230);
}
#notMaskedPath {
  stroke:none;
  fill:rgb(230,230,230);
}
#riverPath {
  stroke:rgb(50,160,240);
  stroke-width:8;
  fill:none;
}
#maskRect {
  fill:white;
  stroke:none;
}
```

```html
<!--this animation doesn't work in FIREFOX, and not tested in IE11 ad Edge YET, WILL BE FIXED SOON (I HOPE)-->
<div id='cont'>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <mask id='rectMask' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' maskContentUnits='userSpaceOnUse' transform='scale(1)'>
        <rect x='0' y='0' width="0" height="850" id='maskRect'>
          <animate attributeName="width"
                   keyTimes="0; 0.4; 0.5; 1"
                   values="0; 670; 670; 0"
                   dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </rect>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path id='maskedPath' d='m 0,0 l 650,0 -100,850 -550,0 z' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='riverPath' d='m 653,0 l -100,850' mask='url(#rectMask)'/>
    <path id='notMaskedPath' d='m 655,0 l 650,0 0,850 -750,0 z'/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: sry, m8! it's my fault, i forgot to say - it's must be cross-browser multi use solution. if i will use SMILL - it's be duplication of all my events with mask in project, now i'm understandt, that here is no single solution with keyframes "width" animation. Only wooden legs... Looks like, i need to try jquery animate, or change 'width' on 'transform:translate'.

Comment: CSS will only work in Chrome right now (maybe Safari?). SMIL will work in Chrome & Firefox (& IE if you use the FakeSmile polyfill).  It is the best cross-browser solution - other than perhaps one of the JS animation libraries.

Comment: deprecated... i hate to live on the edge of times, SMILL is deprecated, CSS doesn't work. By the way, CSS is working in Opera toо. I've heard about fake smile, this is so old polyfill, thx.

Comment: AFAIK SMIL animation is staying in Chrome for the foreseeable future. Chrome postponed indefinitely their plans to remove it, due to lots of negative feedback.

Comment: my solution - js setTimeout function, and nothing more,